# AJAX loading a page without reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to load content from a new page using AJAX. The test website I am working on is [dev.dog-company.com](http://dev.dog-company.com).

This is my code:

```
$('a[rel="load"]').click(function(){
    //var siteurl = ""; 
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", '#');
    $('#slider-wrapper').slideUp();
    $('#content').wrap('<div id="wrap"></div>').css('opacity', '0.75').css('background-color', 'black');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        success : function(data){
            var response = $(data);
            var head= response.find('head');
            var slider = response.find('#slider-wrapper');
            var content = response.find('#content');
            $('#content').unwrap('<div id="wrap"></div>')
            jQuery("head").html(head);
            if(slider != null)
                jQuery("#slider-wrapper").html(slider).slideDown();
            jQuery("#content").html(content);
            return false;
        }
    $(this).attr("href", link);

    })
    });
```

I am trying load the content on click but the page reload everytime without the click working. Also I am not sure if I need to be doing something else other than what I am doing to my code. The rel="load" is only on home, info->AboutUs & FAQ.

Your help is appreciated.

**Update:**

I still can't get it to work. This is my latest code. And the site is still running it. When i use the debugging for chrome it never goes through my code. is it the re="load" that is causing the problem?

**Update:**

My initial problem was not having the document ready. But not I think the way I am parsing the information isn't working. I tried find and filter both seem to not work correctly. Also how do I change the url in the browser after I it pushes the post.

**Update**

After a lot of messing around with it I got it to partially work. One thing I can't do it replace head. and then the data pushed in slider is there but it does not seem to work on the website. It doesn't slide down like I have it in the code.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$('a[rel="load"]').click(function(e){
    //var siteurl = ""; 
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#slider-wrapper').slideUp();
    $('#content').wrap('<div id="wrap-overlay"></div>');
    /*$('#wrap').css({
        'opacity': '0.75',
        'background-color': 'black',
        'z-index' : '10'
        });*/
    $.ajax({
    //ajax setting
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(data){
            //parse data
            var response = $("<div>").html(data);
            console.log(typeof(response));
            console.log(response);
            //var head = response.find('<head>').html();
            slider = response.find('#slider-wrapper').html();
            var content = response.find('#content').html();
            console.log(content);
            //console.log(head);
            //console.log(slider);
            //Post data
            $('#content').unwrap();
            //jQuery("head").empty().append(head);
            if(slider != null){
                jQuery("#slider-wrapper").empty().slideDown().append(slider);
            }
            jQuery("#content").empty().append(content);
            return false;
        }
    })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a[rel="load"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

You need to stop default browser behaviour on link click, which is following it.

Comment: I added it but it keeps refreshing. Not sure why.